# WebRequest removing Authorization header when SSL page using proxy

Tags: c#, proxy, system.net.httpwebrequest

I'm trying to connect to a website using WebRequest and a proxy that has basic Authorization. When connecting to a http site works fine but if I try to connect to a https site get 401 error, looking at network monitor when I try to connect to a https site, don't know why the Authorization header its not present.

Already tried add NetworkCredentials at both proxy and WebRequest no luck either.

```
IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://proxyaddress:port");
                    HttpWebRequest conn = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
                    conn.Method = "GET";
                    String encoded = System.Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("username:password"));
                    conn.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + encoded);
                    conn.PreAuthenticate = true;
                    conn.Proxy = proxy;
                    conn.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue recently where our company proxy stripped Basic auth headers (since it is not secure) when making an external API request to prevent leakage, the only way around this was to order a developer proxy for that URL so that there where no authentications or interceptions. If you have access to the proxy try to configure it to allow Basic auth.

Comment: Not the case, there is no proxy between, the header is stripped before exiting my machine.